# How to extract score from similarity search when doing RAG with LangChain, GPT and Chainlit UI?

Tags: python, openai-api, information-retrieval, langchain, large-language-model

I'm doing RAG (retrieval augmentation generator) using LangChain and OpenAI's GPT, through Chainlit UI. The chain_type I'm using is "map_rerank".

I'm already able to extract the answer and the source document.

But I can't find a way to extract the score from the similarity search and print it in the message for the UI.

Follows the code.

First I set the variables:

```
@on_chat_start
def init():
    llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
        deployment_name=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
        model_name=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_MODEL_NAME,
        openai_api_base=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT,
        openai_api_version=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_VERSION,
        openai_api_key=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
        openai_api_type=saci_constants.AZURE_OPEN_API_TYPE,
        temperature=saci_constants.TEMPERATURE,
        streaming=True,
        callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()],
    )

    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(
        deployment=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_ADA_EMBEDDING_DEPLOYMENT_NAME,
        model=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_ADA_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME,
        openai_api_base=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ENDPOINT,
        openai_api_key=saci_constants.AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
        openai_api_type=saci_constants.AZURE_OPEN_API_TYPE,
        chunk_size=saci_constants.AZURE_CHUNK_SIZE,
    )

    faiss_db = FAISS.load_local(
        saci_constants.FAISS_DATABASE_PATH,
        embeddings,
    )

    retriever = faiss_db.as_retriever(
        search_type="similarity_score_threshold",
        search_kwargs={"score_threshold": 0.5, "k": 3},
    )

    question_generator = LLMChain(
        llm=llm,
        prompt=CONDENSE_QUESTION_PROMPT,
        verbose=True,
    )

    doc_chain = load_qa_with_sources_chain(
        llm,
        chain_type="map_rerank",
        return_intermediate_steps=False,
        verbose=True,
    )

    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
        llm=llm,
        memory_key="chat_history",
        return_messages=True,
        input_key="question",
        output_key="answer",
        max_token_limit=1000,
        # k=1,
    )

    conversational_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain(
        retriever=retriever,
        question_generator=question_generator,
        combine_docs_chain=doc_chain,
        return_source_documents=True,
        memory=memory,
        rephrase_question=False,
        verbose=True,
    )

    # # Set chain as a user session variable
    cl.user_session.set("conversation_chain", conversational_chain)
```

Some observations from the code above. I can't set True for intermediate_steps, since I will get more than one output and the UI run don't accept it.

After setting the variables, I run the chain, get the results, extract the sources from the metadata and pass to the UI:

```
@on_message
async def main(message: str):
    chat_history = []

    # Read chain from user session variable
    chain = cl.user_session.get("conversation_chain")

    # Run the chain
    res = chain({"question": message, "chat_history": chat_history})

    # Extract sources from the documents' metadata
    sources = [doc.metadata.get("source") for doc in res["source_documents"]]

    # Send the answer and the text elements to the UI
    await cl.Message(content=f'ANSWER: {res["answer"]}, SOURCES: {set(sources)}').send()
```

I'm having a hard time to get the score output. It prints in the terminal, but I can't save it or get the UI to show. I tried  to ask for the prompt to extract that, but half of the times it ignores, I want to extract the value myself.